# Getting VIN number from Car's OBD-II Port

Tags: obd-ii

I'm currently trying to build a device that can read Car's VIN number and send it over Bluetooth connection to an Android phone..

Yes, I'm aware that **not** all car support this. So far what I'm aware of is by the ELM327 (to communicate data from car to bluetooth module) and the HC-05 (to communicate data from ELM327 to Android).

But, I'm quite unsure on how to make this works, since I have 0 (zero) experience with the OBD-II. I'd appreciate if anyone could help me with reference and stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to communicate with OBD-II device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095470/how-to-communicate-with-obd-ii-device)